# How to get exact live location of website user?

Tags: android, node.js, web, location, web-development-server

Is there any method through which I can get live exact location of website user such that I should able to see is the user is available in 50 - 100 m² area ?

Is it possible through nodeJs and if not then any other way.

Is it possible through Android development ?

Suppose i have full access of user device now is it possible ?

Comment: From a web page, you would use the [Gelocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), but the end-user would have to allow permission.  Once the location is obtained by javascript running in the web page, it could send that to your server.

Comment: An Android application can use Android APIs for determining the user's location (the Android app will also have to have appropriate permissions to use those APIs).

Comment: Is this solution meet my requirement which I mentioned above ?

Comment: You will have to study the different gelocation APIs and see what they say about the location accuracy and perhaps even try them in desired circumstances.  Unobstructed GPS is very accurate (under 10 feet), but it is not always unobstructed.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(res => console.log(res))

output : GeolocationPosition {coords: GeolocationCoordinates, timestamp: 1640926681834}coords: GeolocationCoordinatesaccuracy: 20altitude: nullaltitudeAccuracy: nullheading: nulllatitude: 28.6366846longitude: 77.4627344speed: null[[Prototype]]: GeolocationCoordinatestimestamp: 1640926681834[[Prototype]]: GeolocationPosition
```

you can easily use this code, if you want to use in live website than ssl(https) and location must be enable and on local it'll work fine.